# Turning off 'snapping' associated with drawing rather than features using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, snapping, annotation, arcgis-10.6

I am using ArcMap 10.6.

I have an ArcMap MXD where I have created annotation and am adjusting its placement, but it seems to keep snapping to an unseen grid and I can't place things exactly where I want them.

I am looking for a way to turn off this behaviour so the labels stay where I drop them.

I have done some internet searching but keep coming up with answers related to feature snapping to other features, or to the guides at the edge of the neatline, whereas I do not have those guides in my MXD and am not snapping to another feature, but rather whatever invisible grid is bring applied to the MXD.

Any help?

Comment: Are you using map or database annotation? Are you using the annotation toolbar (DB annotation) or just doing graphics editing? It makes a big difference.

Comment: database annotation.  No toolbar specific to annotation, unless you are referring to the annotation selection tool in the Editor toolbar.  I have tried doing the move selecting with the drawing arrow pointer and the feature editing pointer tool, same result both times which was why I thought maybe there is an invisible grid enabled it is trying to snap to.

Comment: Is this feature-linked annotation? Are you making small moves or big ones out toward the edges of your data? Have you tried a brand new MXD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the option (the general ArcMap option, not the feature snapping option, see first picture) there are 4 different setting for snapping one of these are "grid" (the other are guide, ruler and margin) you could try to disable all of them, if that still doesn't work you could try to set the snapping tolerance to a very low value.

In the feature snapping option (second picture) there are setting to activate basemap snapping and feature service snapping and again a snapping tolerance setting

By checking all of this you should be able to solve your problem

(picture are from 10.3 version so there may be some difference with your, and as it's in french my translation for the option may be off...)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any features that do not have a symbology (e.g. they are symbolized based on a category, but you don't have some of the classes symboloized and have the All other values option turned off).

I've found that in some of my larger MXDs, this can cause issues with snapping and I'll end up snapping to these un-symbolized features.

If that's the case, the easiest way to fix it would probably be to use a definition query to remove the other layers. If you only have a few classes, you can do something like "Field In ('class1', 'class2')".

Comment: There are some of those, but those layers are all turned off, so in theory Arcmap's snapping should be ignoring them.  I also don't get the same behaviour when opening the MXD on a different machine so i am thinking it is a setting in ArcMap, and that PC is running a freshly installed ESRI Desktop suite as opposed to the one that does not reproduce the problem which is an older install with settings already adjusted.  I just can't seem to find the setting...